# How can I change the shape of points in a scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, scatter-plot, lineseries, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJS to create a scatter chart.
is there a way in which I can add custom shapes or images as point shape.say maybe small images/icons of laptops and smartphones instead of squares or circles?

```
const smartPhonesSeries = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Circle })
const laptopsSeries = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Square })
const laptopsSeries = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Square })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PointSeries only supports the shapes listed in PointShape enumeration.

As of now, rendering any custom images is not supported with LCJS accelerated rendering.